# Getting error 500 .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

I'm looking to parse url and get this format localhost/public/index.php?url=..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any apache error log to clearly answer your question.

This probably be due to error in .htaccess

From the code you provided, there is an error in

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

There should not be a space after **QSA,**

change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this should probably solve your problem (not sure because you haven't provided the apache error log).

PS: Make sure your rewrite module is enabled in *httpd.conf*